# How can I crop my UIPickerView?

Tags: xcode, uipickerview, crop

Here is my horizontal UIPickerView (by rotate & scale the ori UIpicker) : htp://s7.postimage.org/qzez9d0pn/Original.png

And now, what I want to do is cut off these two spaces : http://s7.postimage.org/bryzp08uz/Process.png

To have this better look result : http://s7.postimage.org/6ulf3w6vv/Result.png

**Somebody please help me how to do it...?**

my rotate & scale code :

```
thePickerView.delegate = self;
thePickerView.showsSelectionIndicator =YES;
thePickerView.center = CGPointMake(xVar, yVar); // position
CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-3.14/2); // rotate
rotate = CGAffineTransformScale(rotate, 0.1, 1); // scale
[thePickerView setTransform:rotate];

UILabel *theview[num]; 
CGAffineTransform rotateItem = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14/2);

for (int i=0;i<num;i++) {  
    theview[i] = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    theview[i].text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i+1];
    theview[i].textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    theview[i].frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 100, 100);
    theview[i].backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    theview[i].textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    theview[i].shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    theview[i].shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1,-1);
    theview[i].adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

    theview[i].transform = CGAffineTransformScale(rotateItem, 1, 10);
}
itemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int j=0;j<num;j++) {[itemArray addObject:theview[j]];}
[thePickerView selectRow:row inComponent:0 animated:NO];
[self.view addSubview:thePickerView];
```

Answer (score 0):

My temporary solution while searching & waiting for better coding answer is create an overlay background image then transparent the desire space of PickerView =.=